# position restarts gallery in listview

Tags: android, listview, gallery

In my application i am using a Gallery view in Listview.While scrolling Listview item   shows the first position. means in my screen 4 rows are visible 0,1,2,3. To  view the fifth row i am scrolling up. in that case 5th position value shows as 0 instead of 5. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
public class TestprojectActivity extends Activity {
ListView listView;
LayoutInflater inflater;
int gloppos;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ladapter=new ListViewAdapter(this);
    listView.setAdapter(ladapter);
}
private class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
  Context context;
  public ListViewAdapter(Context context){
    this.context=context; 
    inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

   }
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 30;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return  position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Gallery mygallery;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mygallary,null);
        mygallery=(Gallery)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listgallary);
        convertView.setTag(mygallery);
      }else{
        mygallery=(Gallery)convertView.getTag();
      }
    Toast.makeText(TestprojectActivity.this,"List pos "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    gloppos=position;
    GallaryAdapter adpt=new GallaryAdapter(position);
    mygallery.setAdapter(adpt);
    return convertView;
  }


}
private class GallaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
  int listpos;  
  public GallaryAdapter(int pos){
      listpos=pos;
    }
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 10;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null){

          convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallaryitems,null);
          TextView text=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
          text.setText("GALLARYPOS  "+position);
          TextView num=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.num);

          num.setText("LSTVIEWPOS  "+listpos);
        }
        Toast.makeText(TestprojectActivity.this,"calledin gallery "+gloppos,    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show(); 
    return convertView;
  }

}
```

}

Comment: post your custom adapter code (if you can)

Comment: I think that list view is taking whole gallery view as its one child. So when you are moving it up then in second child again same gallery view is loading.. post your code snippet. to make it more clear.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply i posted my code see above code. thanks

Comment: Finally i solved the problem. just i replaced the layout_hieght attribute  from wrap_content to Fill_parent now its working fine